# Restore apple software file

Tags: macos, updates

I have broken my software file, but I don't know how to I can fix it with Apple's own software updater again.

Can anyone suggest how to fix it.

Comment: Wow we're being spoilt with riches today - go on, I'll bite, can you give us A LOT more information please so we have a chance of helping you.

Answer (score 1):

If you're referring to software that comes with OSX, like for example Mail.app, that is somehow not functioning in the same way it did when you first start using the computer, you can use this program with your restore cd's that came with the computer or operating system:
http://www.charlessoft.com/Pacifist_Documentation/English/index.html
download link [here](http://www.charlessoft.com)

If you don't have your restore disc, you could use the disc they sell for your operating system, even older ones are available online, like through Amazon.

Pardon me if I'm not answering your question, good luck.